# How to hide the changes of a folder on Github?

Tags: github, github-pages

The documentation of my repository is in the `docs/` folder and is hosted by Github. I know I can place this in another branch, but I prefer it this way. Is there any way I can hide all changes from the `docs/` folder in my commits?

My builds are setup to regenerate the documentation whenever the code changes, but this results in hundreds of files being changed with things like timestamps, making the commit diff unreadable.

Comment: If the docs are generated, not source, don't include them in the repo, `.gitignore` them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You answered your question earlier... by making the `docs/` folder in another branch like "gh-pages" while your "master" won't show those commits to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding changes with git is not possible (does not really make sense if you think about it. If the docs are completely generated I recommend to not even have them in a git repo at all. (just use .gitignore for the folder)

If you want the files to be in a git repo maybe you can use git submodules (https://git-scm.com/book/de/v1/Git-Tools-Submodule)
This way you do not have all the changes in your main code repository.